# HowTo draw border for QTableWidget row?

Tags: qt, qt4, qtablewidget

I'm trying to make a border for rows in `QTableWidget` with different ways, but all solutions don't respond my requirements. All that I *want, is to draw a rectangle around a whole row*. I had try `QStyledItemDelegate` class, but that is not my way, because delegates are used only for item[ row, column ], not for the whole rows or columns.

Here is wrong solution:

```
/// @brief Рисуем границу вокруг строки. 
class DrawBorderDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
     DrawBorderDelegate( QObject* parent = 0 ) : QStyledItemDelegate( parent ) {}
     void paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const;

}; // DrawBorderDelegate

void DrawBorderDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
     QStyleOptionViewItem opt = option;

     painter->drawRect( opt.rect );

     QStyledItemDelegate::paint( painter, opt, index );  
}
```

And somewhere in code:

```
tableWidget->setItemDelegateForRow( row, new DrawBorderDelegate( this ) );
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you considered that you may need to create your own view?  Alternately, create a delegate that looks at the column for the index it is painting, and draws the appropriate sides of the rectangle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your solution was not far wrong. You just need to be a bit more selective about which edges of the rectangle you draw:

```
void DrawBorderDelegate::paint( QPainter* painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem& option, const QModelIndex& index ) const
{
     const QRect rect( option.rect );

     painter->drawLine( rect.topLeft(), rect.topRight() );
     painter->drawLine( rect.bottomLeft(), rect.bottomRight() );

     // Draw left edge of left-most cell
     if ( index.column() == 0 )
         painter->drawLine( rect.topLeft(), rect.bottomLeft() );

     // Draw right edge of right-most cell
     if ( index.column() == index.model()->columnCount() - 1 )
         painter->drawLine( rect.topRight(), rect.bottomRight() );

     QStyledItemDelegate::paint( painter, option, index );
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Caleb Huitt - cjhuitt & Clare Macrae Thank you for that hint! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
  #include <QTableWidget>     
  QTableWidget* table = new QTableWidget();

  table->resize(400, 250);

  table->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
  table->setColumnCount(3);
  table->setRowCount(2);

  //Set Header Label Texts Here
  table->verticalHeader ()->hide();
  table->horizontalHeader()->hide();

  table->setItem(0,0,new QTableWidgetItem("CELL 1"));
  table->setItem(0,1,new QTableWidgetItem("CELL 2"));
  table->setItem(0,2,new QTableWidgetItem("CELL 3"));

  table->setItem(1,0,new QTableWidgetItem("CELL 4"));
  table->setItem(1,1,new QTableWidgetItem("CELL 5"));
  table->setItem(1,2,new QTableWidgetItem("CELL 6"));

  table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
  table->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
  table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::NoSelection);

  table-> setObjectName (QString :: fromUtf8 ("table_"));
  table->show();
```

Stylesheet:

```
QTableWidget
{
    background-color : none;
    gridline-color: white;    // this border for rows and columns
    color:#ffffff;
}

QTableWidget#table_{
     border:1px solid #ffffff;   // this border for total table
}
```

[**sample output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXVWN.png)

[image]

Hope this simple way to helps!!!

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: paint( QPainter* painter... this method will useful for drawing the shapes, but **qtableWidget will be displaying data** only means we go this method to simplifies your work.. using qss stylesheet we can give the border like the above method.. I attached sample output also..