# Is it possible to draw focus rect for whole QTableWidget row?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have a `QTableWidget` simple table, which have many rows and columns. So, what I need, is to *draw **focus rect** over the whole selected row*, as `QTreeView/QTreeWidget` could do.

Is it possible?

PS. As I could understand from the Qt `qtablewidget.h` sources, this feature does not realized...

Many thanks.

Comment: There is code in [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7416503/howto-draw-border-for-qtablewidget-row/7422615#7422615) that shows how to draw rectangles around whole rows in QTableWidget objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate all columns, get all QTableWidgetItems for your selected row and change the background color to blue.

Comment: I have used custom widgets in my "simple table", so if I do so, widgets with background will be shown as not viewable... I'm trying to find solution to *focus*, but not for *selection*. Thnks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You want to select the whole row?  Use QAbstractItemView's [selectionBehavior](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionBehavior-enum) property.

Comment: No, I want to draw focus rect over the selected row.

Comment: @mosg: Do you have a custom delegate to do the drawing?  That might help.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't find methods how to change focus rect, that's why I'm asking here... Just for now, I'm able to draw custom rects for the row in QTableWidget, but I need draw focus for the whole row! Thnks.

Comment: @mosg: If you have custom delegates, you can do other drawing to indicate the row that has focus.  I don't know if there's an easy way to adjust the focus rect that is drawn by default.  You might have some success with inheriting the view and messing with its paint event, or with looking into style stuff.